# Error using imagemagick on mamp

Tags: macos, imagemagick, mamp

I am trying to convert a pdf to jpeg. So i created a bash file :

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/convert "ODR20120641.pdf" "document.jpg" 2>&1
```

But i got this error message:

```
convert: missing an image filename `document.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3015.
```

I am on lion, and i installed imagemagick using homebrew. When i run this command in the terminal, every thing works fine. But when i use php, it fails :

```
$return = exec('./generate');
var_dump($return);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have access to php what happens if you run the code directly using exec? The error is probably not with document.jpg but a problem with finding or modifying the pdf file.

```
$array=array(); 
echo "<pre>"; 
exec("/usr/local/bin/convert ODR20120641.pdf document.jpg 2>&1", $array);  
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>";  
echo "</pre>";
```